# How do I read a procedure (lambda) from input?

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to hit in the lambda expression, then the function evaluates it with some arguments. Is it something like `(read)`? But I don't want my input to become strings or symbols.

```
(define (foo)
  (define my-func (something like "read"?))
  (display (my-func 2)))
```

so when I say `(lambda (x) (add1 x))` it returns 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can evaluate the symbolic representation that `read` will generate using [`eval`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html).

```
(define (foo)
  (define ns (make-base-namespace))
  (define my-func (eval (read) ns))
  (display (my-func 2)))
```

Comment: Do you know how to autofill `(lambda (x) ...)` if I only input `(+ x 1)`?

Comment: @Young That's a pretty vague question. Finding variable names inside the input and generating suitable scaffolding is a complicated task with various solutions depending on what are trying to do.